# Results about Schrödinger equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

Does anyone know any paper or book that deals with Schrodinger equations, specifically on asymptotic properties like blowup or limitation of solution when time goes to infinity using Schrödinger semigroup properties? I ask this, as I have seen several papers in which heat equations are studied and good properties are obtained using the heat semigroup, I am in doubt whether the schrödinger semigroup can be obtained good results, but so far I have not found anything about.

Comment: solutions to the Schrödinger equation do not have the large-$t$ limitations of the heat equation, they are quasiperiodic in time (it's the difference between a real and imaginary exponent)

Comment: yes, Schrödinger is dispersive, while heat is diffusive